# Basic broadcast example using agora.io not working

Tags: audio, broadcast, agora.io

I'm trying to get agora.io's audio broadcasting working on a webpage, following [this example](https://docs.agora.io/en/Audio%20Broadcast/start_live_audio_web?platform=Web).

Everything works, *if* I also broadcast video. If I broadcast audio *only*, nothing shows, nothing is heard, but no errors are showing in the console.

Here's my HTML:

```
 <div class="video-grid" id="video">
   <div class="video-view">
     <div id="local_stream" class="video-placeholder"></div>
     <div id="local_video_info" class="video-profile hide"></div>
     <div id="video_autoplay_local" class="autoplay-fallback hide"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Here's my Agora code:

```
var rtc = {
  client: null,
  joined: false,
  published: false,
  localStream: null,
  remoteStreams: [],
  params: {}
};

// Options for joining a channel
//Self-generated token
var option = {
  appID: "{{myappid}}",
  channel: "event-2123",
  uid: "1",
  token: "{{mytoken}}"
}

rtc.client = AgoraRTC.createClient({mode: "live", codec: "h264"});

// Initialize the client
rtc.client.init(option.appID, function () {
  console.log("init success");

    // Join a channel
    rtc.client.join(option.token ? option.token : null, option.channel, option.uid ? +option.uid : null, function (uid) {
        console.log("join channel: " + option.channel + " success, uid: " + uid);
        rtc.params.uid = uid;



        rtc.client.setClientRole("host");

        rtc.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
            streamID: rtc.params.uid,
            audio: true,
            video: true,
            screen: false,
        })

        // Initialize the local stream
        rtc.localStream.init(function () {
            console.log("--------");
          console.log("init local stream success");
          // play stream with html element id "local_stream"
          rtc.localStream.play("local_stream");

            // Publish the local stream
            rtc.client.publish(rtc.localStream, function (err) {
              console.log("publish failed");
              console.error(err);
            })


        }, function (err) {
          console.error("init local stream failed ", err);
        });



      }, function(err) {
        console.error("client join failed", err)
    })

  }, (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

This works (but not, it seems, on Safari). But If I change the stream parameters to this, nothing works:

```
        rtc.localStream = AgoraRTC.createStream({
            streamID: rtc.params.uid,
            audio: true,
            video: false,
            screen: false,
        })
```

I've noticed that, in some browsers, the video is muted by default. So, if no interface elements are showing, and muting is 'on', perhaps this is the source of the problem?

How to make this work?

Comment: Can you add some logs and links? Which demo are you using? 
https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-web-showcase/examples/OpenLive-Web/#/

I am able to disable the camera here with the mic still enabled

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, the link to the example disappeared in my question. I put it back. That demo works for me, too (at that URL).

Comment: Added some details. I can provide a log tomorrow, but the console returns no errors.

Comment: That link is to build the quickstart guide. Looks like you may have the wrong call sequence. Can you add the source code to your question?

Comment: Edited the question to add code.